# Typescript Cannot find module (TS2307)

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

I know this is a common question but I have gone through almost every "TS cannot find module" question and none of the solutions worked for me or didnt apply to my case.

I am debugging sln on VS2019. When I first cloned the repo I ran into [this TS error saying it couldnt find modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9g2B.png). I ran npm install which didnt work. I tried installing each one manually and that just led to more problems. The modules should be there since the build is successful right?

The project uses typescript 3.7 so I tried updating that to see if it does anything. Still no good.

Here is the tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include":[
    "node_modules/angular2-masonry",
    "app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Just to add, this project works fine on my partners machine, so I think it is some package or something related I am missing, but I dont know what. Let me know if there is more information I can provide.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do as follow,

1. Delete *node_modules* folder
2. Delete *package-lock.json* file
3. Run: `npm install`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Still getting same error.